# Wrong UTF-8 string parsing in GWT JSON

Tags: java, json, gwt, utf-8

my stack is overflow :):):):) I can't find the solution...

I'm developing a server-client application.
My GWT client running in browser. Communicate with my C++ server by:
GWT-JSON -> lighttpd -> libfcgi -> cgicc -> libjson -> C++ application

My problem:
The server response with a JSON string to client's request. This response contains UTF-8 strings. Accent characters encoded correctly with "\uXXXX" in response. For example: "Á" encoded: "\u00C3\u0081".
The client extract the string from JSON string. But the extracted string contains bad encoded characters. :(:(:(:(

Lucky, I can narrow the problem to JSON-GWT. Here is a code to demonstrate the problem, running in client side only in GWT:

```
String response="{ \"test\" : \"\\u00C3\\u0081\\u00C3\\u0089\\u00C5\\u00B0\" }"; //"ÁÉÜ" in UTF-8
JSONObject json=JSONParser.parseStrict(response).isObject();
String s1=json.get("test").isString().stringValue();
Window.alert(s1);
byte[] b1=s1.getBytes();
```

The results:

```
Alert is: "ÃÃ‰Å°" instead of "ÁÉÜ"
s1="ÃÃ‰Å°" instead of "ÁÉÜ"
b1=[ 0xc3, 0x83, 0xc2, 0x81, 0xc3, 0x83, 0xc2, 0x89, 0xc3, 0x85, 0xc4, 0xb0 ] (incorrect)
```

Here is an another test:

```
String s2="ÁÉŰ";
Window.alert(s2);
byte[] b2=s2.getBytes();
```

The results:

```
Alert: "ÁÉÜ" (correct)
s2="ÁÉÜ" (correct)
b2=[ 0xc3, 0x81, 0xc3, 0x89, 0xc5, 0xb0 ] (correct, same as in "response" string above)
```

I think, the JSONParser.parseStrict or JSONObject.get().isString().stringValue() can't handle correctly the UTF-8 characters...

Any idea? :(:(:(:(

Additional information:
The request and response Content-Type is "application/json; charset=UTF-8". Source code files and the development environment use UTF-8. The HTML page in browser encoding also UTF-8.

I have problem only with the response only. The request character coding/encoding is correct.

Thank you for any help,
Tibor

**Update1:**

```
String s1b=new String(s1.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Returns:
 s1b="ÁÉÜ" (correct)

It's ugly, and strange. Why I need to convert UTF-8 string to ISO-8859-1 to get an UTF-8 string again? I don't understand... :(:(:(

**Update2:**

If I disable "\u00xx" escaping in JSON writer in server side, all works as expected. But this is not a good idea according to RFC4627 :((((. In this mode, the JSON string transports the non-printable characters (0xc3, 0x81, 0xc3, 0x89, 0xc5, 0xb0) ("ÁÉÚ" in UTF-8) without any encoding.... :(:(:(
GWT JSON parser expands the UTF-8 character correctly, and the alert displays correct characters.
I think continuously, the wrong decoding is near to GWT JSON decoding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is broken; it doesn't use JSON correctly. Unicode escapes in JSON correspond to UTF-16 code units, so `Á` should be encoded as `\u00c1`, *not* as the 2-character string you quote.

Comment: Change the line example above:
String response="{ \"test\" : \"\\u00c1\\u00c9\\u0170\" }"; //"ÁÉÜ" in UTF-16

All works correctly. Thanks..